# stargazer in markdown not reading the table when knit to pdf

Tags: r, datatables, format, r-markdown, stargazer

I'm using stargazer for tables but everytime I knit to pdf it doesn't read the latex code and my pdf does not have a table. How do i get rmarkdown to produce an actual table?
[image]

I've tried lots of different stargazer tables, but they all have this same output when i knit to pdf.

Comment: please share your r markdown code as well. If you can the data that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `asis` option in markdown.

````
---
title: "stargazer in markdown"
author: "Me"
date: "2023-01-11"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

## Stargazer 

```{r}
library(stargazer)
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data=mtcars)
```

```{r, results='asis'}
stargazer(model)
```
````

[image]